# addChildEventListener is showing error while addValueEventListener is giving the value of datasnapshot. why?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

database structure is

[image: Databse Strucutre]

this listner is providing value to model class

```
 ref.child(stateName).child(cityName).child("business").child(user).child("counter").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            ShopCategoryModel  Smodel =  dataSnapshot.getValue( ShopCategoryModel.class);




            servicetype = Smodel.getServicetype();
            int orderleft = Smodel.getOrderleft();
            int uploadsleft = Smodel.getUploadsleft();
            int referralpionts = Smodel.getReferralpionts();
            renewaldate = Smodel.getRenewaldate();
            int vistors = Smodel.getVisitors();
            int ratings = Smodel.getRatings();

            ac_TotalVisitors.setText(""+vistors);
            ac_ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(ratings)));
            ac_Shope_ratings.setText(""+ratings);

            ac_orderleft.setText(""+orderleft);
            ac_Uploadsleft.setText(""+uploadsleft);
            ac_Referralpoints.setText(""+referralpionts);
            ac_renewdate.setText(renewaldate);








            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

while applying addChildEventListener  is showing error

```
 ref.child(stateName).child(cityName).child("business").child(user).child("counter").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            ShopCategoryModel  Smodel =  dataSnapshot.getValue( ShopCategoryModel.class);



            servicetype = Smodel.getServicetype();
            int orderleft = Smodel.getOrderleft();
            int uploadsleft = Smodel.getUploadsleft();
            int referralpionts = Smodel.getReferralpionts();
            renewaldate = Smodel.getRenewaldate();

            int vistors = Smodel.getVisitors();
            int ratings = Smodel.getRatings();

            ac_TotalVisitors.setText(""+vistors);
            ac_ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(ratings)));
            ac_Shope_ratings.setText(""+ratings);

            ac_orderleft.setText(""+orderleft);
            ac_Uploadsleft.setText(""+uploadsleft);
            ac_Referralpoints.setText(""+referralpionts);
            ac_renewdate.setText(renewaldate);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

after this m getting this error

```
 Process: mahendergarh.bhupendra.shaharseller, PID: 18837
                                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type mahendergarh.bhupendra.shaharseller.model.ShopCategoryModel
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at mahendergarh.bhupendra.shaharseller.Sign_in.Account$3.onChildAdded(Account.java:255)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.uv.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.aaf.zzIo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.aal.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

m using each listeners at different time.
please tell me  the reason why this is happening why m getting model class error in addChildEventListener. thanq in advance!!!!

Comment: Not seeing the error, can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: i just add the eroor

Comment: Since I don't know the structure of your firebase database, have you tried the same code in onChildChanged( ) ?

Comment: yeah m fatching same  node in both listners.... u can see my structre now

Answer (score 0):

A `ChildEventListener` fires for each child under the location where you attach it, while a `ValueEventListener` fires for the location itself.

So if you attach the listeners at the same location in the database, the `onChildAdded` fires with the individual properties of the node. So `date`, `orderLeft`, etc.

You typically need a `ChildEventListener` if you have a query or a collection, which you don't have here.

Comment: so we cant fatch norml data node with ChildEventListener ??? but i wann to dosomething onDatachange. what shoud i use now??

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish by using a `ChildEventListener`. If this helps: `ValueEventListener.onDataChange` fires immediately with the current value when you attach the listener.

Comment: i wann to put a condition (if-else) onDatachange but problem with ValueEvent is, it trigers the data  every time when acitvity  is created and that condition also start working without any data being changed in databsed thats why i wann to use 'ChildEventListener'. so suggest me somthing now

Comment: `onChildAdded` will also retrigger for all existing properties when the activity restarts. So let's ignore the `ChildEventListener`, which is only useful on collections and queries, neither is what you're trying right now. Are you looking to only get a callback when there is an actual change in the data? How are you using that in your app? Do you store the current value somewhere?

Comment: actually, my value is already stored in the database. i wanna fetch that stored value first on activity starts and i wann to put a condition when my data is being changed (when ever string get changed) that **if( String.equals("something")){do something})**